# What kind of declarator is this?

Tags: c++, grammar

So I was looking in to C++ grammar for syntax thing, I came across this grammar rule :

```
declarator:
direct-declarator
ptr-operator declarator

direct-declarator:
declarator-id

declarator-id:
id-expression
::opt nested-name-specifier(opt) type-name  <------- oO

type-name:
class-name
enum-name
typedef-name
```

Which made me wonder what kind of declarator has typename in it? Any example would help. Thanks

Comment: Are you really sure you need to read C++ grammar? This is not for weak hearts.

Comment: Where do you see this? That's not what my copy of the standard says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this form it exists only on older versions of C++ standard. I guess that it is there for constructor definitions

```
void SomeClass::SomeClass() {}
```

I'd guess that the following wording

> A class-name has special meaning in a declaration of the class of that
>   name and when qualified by that name using the scope resolution
>   operator :: (5.1, 12.1, 12.4).

is intended to accompany that specific part of the grammar.

Comment: Actually for constructor definitions outside a class that were previously declared within the class (what your example shows)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :) +1

Comment: recent grammars have moved this construction into *id-expression*

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, its not really necessary in the grammar at all, as the grammar can't tell you whether any give identifier is a type_name or not.  The grammar describes as syntactically correct many things that are semantically incorrect.